# Meaning of "[tmp c]=max(S(:,I),[],2); c(I)=1:K; " in MatLab

Tags: r, matlab, cluster-analysis

I am trying to translate the reference implementation of AP Clustering into C++.
This sequence of statements baffles me because it looks as if vector c gets filled with some numbers, and then promptly overwritten with a different set of numbers.  Which makes no sense.  Here is the Matlab code:

```
[tmp c]=max(S(:,I),[],2); c(I)=1:K;
```

The R implementation has something very similar:

```
    c <- max.col(s[, I], ties.method="first")
    c[I] <- 1:K
```

It is true that s is NxN while I is of length K << N. However as I read it, c is the same size as I, so that the final value is just a permutation of 1:K that depends on I but not on the result of the first statement.

I thought I knew what each statement does, but the combination is a mystery.  Please set me straight.

Comment: It is true that s is NxN while I is of length K << N.  However as I read it, c is the same size as I, so that the final value is just a permutation of 1:K that depends on I but not on the result of the first statement.

Comment: Please put the code into the question body, it'll be easier to read with proper code formatting. Also include your comment about the sizes of `s` and the value of `K` in the question itself. The comments are meant to ask for clarification, not to extend the question. You can [edit] your question at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking about the R version: if

> s is NxN while I is of length K << N.

then

- `s[,I]` has dimensions N (rows) x K (columns)
- according to `?max.col`, `max.col` "[f]ind[s] the maximum position for **each row** of a matrix" (emphasis added)
- thus `c` is of length `N` (i.e., equal to the number of *rows* of `s[,I`)

If `I` is of length `K`, then assigning values to `c[I]` will fill in only `K` of the `N` values of `c`, leaving the other `N-K` equal to their original values.

R does vectorized assignment, so `c[I] <- 1:K` is equivalent to (but faster than)

```
for (j in seq(K)) {
    c[I[j]] <- j
}
```

Comment: Aha.  Thank you very much.  Am I correct in supposing that those K values are c[I[1]] == 1, c[I[2]] == 2 and so on?